# Getting refreshed automatically without submitting anything.. in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Help Needed
Issue facing : Getting refreshed automatically without submitting anything.. in php while coming from other page? Tools used: php, html and mysql.

```
    <?php
            session_start();
            ob_start();
            include('connect.php');
            include('functions.php');
            $uid = $_SESSION['user'];
            ?>
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
            <title>Nikon</title>
            </head>

            <body>
        <div id="wecome" style=" margin-top: 120px; margin-left: 660px; margin-right: 20px;">
                <div id="register_detail" style=" margin-top: 35px; margin-left: 30px;">
                  <?php
                  $image=$_POST['image'];
                  $image1=$_POST['image1'];
                 //$comments=$_POST['comments'];
                  $image=($_FILES['image']['name']);
                  $image1=($_FILES['image1']['name']);

                 //This is the directory where images will be saved
                  $target = "images/uploaded/";
                  $targetx = $target . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
                  //Writes the photo to the server
                  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $targetx))
                  {

                  //Tells you if its all ok
                  }
                  else {
                 //Gives and error if its not
                  }

                 $targetx = $target . basename( $_FILES['image1']['name']);

                 //Writes the photo to the server
                 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $targetx))
                 {

                 //Tells you if its all ok
                 }
                 else {
                //Gives and error if its not
                 }
                 if (!$targetx) 
                {
                ///echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
                $errors=1;
                }
                //If no errors registred, print the success message
                    $uid = $_SESSION['user'];
 $sql = "update dealer set image = '$image' ,image1 = '$image1' where id = '$uid'";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    $success =2;
                  ?>
            <?php
                if($success==2)
                {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=thank_u.php">';    
                }
                ?><div id="option1" style="width: 354px; height: 185px;">
                    <img src="images/option_big2.jpg" border="0px" /><br/><br/>
                 </div>
                  <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="option_2.php" method="post">
      <div id="option3" style="width: 350px; height: 55px; margin-left: 380px;">
      <font style="font-size:12px; color:#666666;">Image 1</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="file" id="image" name="image"><br /><br />
      <font style="font-size:12px; color:#666666;">Image 2</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="file" id="image1" name="image1"><br/>
      <div id="font" style="margin-top: 4px;">
      <font style="font-size:12px;color:#666666;">( jpg, gif, png files only )</font></div>
                  </div><br/><br/>
       <div id="submit" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align:right; margin-right: 110px;">
       <input type= "hidden" name="test" value="2"><input type="submit" value ="Submit">
                  </div>
                  </form>
                  </div>

               </th>
              </tr>

            </table>
            </body>
            </html>

 Please help me in solving it urgently...
```

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=thank_u.php">` is the reason.. the page gets refreshed every second

Comment: Basically after submitting i want my user to get redirected to thanku.php page... but now when im coming through option page to uploading page (current). it is not allowing me to submit anything and automaticaly redirects me to thank u page...:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have assigned `$success =2` directly. Assign it after uploading the content. i mean something like

```
if(move_uploaded_file() == TRUE)
{
    $success=2;
}
```

And don't use "refresh" in `<meta>`. You want to redirect the user after form submission,right! then why don't you use `header:` or `redirect`?

Comment: have one more question should i post here or need to add one more question...??

Comment: @user1594507  post as a new question so that other users can also have a look at it

Comment: hey bro i have tried the header stuff but its not working .. i meant the redirection working in localhost but when im puttin it on live server its not working...:(

Comment: can you post your code? @AjitSingh

Comment: <?php
 if($success==2)
 {
  echo "Thank u for uploading";
  header('Location:  thank_u.php');
  exit();
 }
 ?>

Comment: give complete link like `header("location:http://www.blabla.com/thank_u.php")`

Comment: bro still not working .... your can view online..http://webinfinity.in/nikon_new/option_1.php

Comment: The email validation isn't allowing me in.Try removing `exit();` after `header`

Comment: If problem persists, go with another approach.


 This isn't recommended but you have no choice when header isn't working.

Comment: Try this <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="your link"; </script>

Comment: use ajit.singh@webinfinity.in in email validation..

Comment: k whatever, try the javascript code which i've posted above